# Arguments for/against bike lanes?

Tags: safety, traffic, advocacy

What are the arguments for and against bike lanes? Can anyone summarize the best reasons they're good for and bad for cyclists and automobile drivers?

For example, Are there some environments particularly suited for bike lanes? Are there some types of locales that would be particularly suited for them, where they wouldn't cause resentment?

Comment: I think the question is biased, and you won't get the proper answer. You didn't aks for pro's and con's of bike lane, but for pro's and con's of how the local mayor decided to implement bike lane. Bike lane are good (see The Netherlands example) but in the rest of the world, we can see many example of wrongly implementing bike lanes. Perhaps, you should rephrase your question.

Comment: @Huygens - I tagged this question with "advocacy" for a reason. The purpose of this question *is* to ask for good arguments, not for pros and cons. That might be another question, if you can think of  way to do it non-argumentatively and sufficiently different from this question.

Comment: No one would ask a similar question by replacing in your question bike lanes by sidewalk and cyclists by pedestrians. Of course it's because there are no pro's or con's for sidewalk, they are a necessity. However, one could talk how stupidly in his city a sidewalk was made (e.g. too narrow, always flooded as soon as it's raining, etc.) So my comment was perhaps to reformulate your question so we could share each of us our bad experiences with some cycle lanes implementation, and how we could contact our politicians to fix those. That's almost what you asked in the 2nd paragraphs.

Comment: @Huygens - Part of advocacy is convincing people to allow bike lanes in the first place. Implementation is a separate, very important question, but it's not what I had in mind here. (Let's move this to meta if discussion is going to continue, okay?)

Comment: I have not found much use for bike lanes because motorists ignore and use these too. I suggest that you use the pavement if necessary, especially if you are being forced off the road by motorists who are ignoring your presence or do not even see you. I emphasise safety and to ride on the pavement with caution. Also, I recommend that you memorise an insulting rejoinder to pedestrians who complain that you are using the pavements. Always remember that these could be ignorant people who are unaware of how the dangerous the roads are for cyclists and could be guilty of parking on the pavement.

Comment: I'd rather have no bike lane than a bad bike lane.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**AGAINST**

One of my primary issues with bike lanes is that motorists tend to think that you have to stay in that lane.  So when you have to move right because of debris, garbage cans or parked cars in the lane it further annoys ill-informed drivers.

Additionally, drivers come to expect you to be out of traffic, riding on the shoulder, and will squeeze by you closer.

Many bike lanes are placed immediately to the left (traffic-side, may be right depending on the country) of the parking area, so if you remain in the bike lane you are in the "door zone".

Bike lanes tend to increase confusion and conflict at intersections, either forcing the cars to cross the lanes in an awkward manner, or enticing cyclists to filter to the front of the lane and possibly blocking turning actions by motorists. Bike lanes encourage passing on the right, which can be a very dangerous action for the cyclist.

Finally - by law in most places **every lane is a bike lane**... there is no possible way for designated bike lanes and routes to be marked to every destination I would like to visit, and by law when I am in the lane **I am traffic, I'm not blocking traffic**. (*sorry, I get a little militant about bike lanes, especially when they are the primary focus of improved cycling infrastructure rather than wider roads with calmer traffic.*)

**FOR**

As someone with some experience teaching workshops for new bike commuters, I find that the existence of convenient bike lanes and multi-use paths makes taking those first trips easier.  Novice commuters feel more comfortable riding on a marked bike lane, even if they don't realize that they may be marginally less safe in a bike lane at the far right edge of the roadway, generally a riskier position.

There are some places, like one particularly popular area in Salt Lake City, where rather than position a lane demarcated with white lines to the side of the travel lane, the DOT painted a wide green lane with bike icons almost in the middle of the right-most travel lane and erected signs that read "Bicycles Allowed Full Use of Lane."   This is not a bike lane, but a hybrid or shared-lane, and  I love it because it reinforces the fact that bikes are traffic, and roads must be shared.

Comment: Good answer; I'd like to add that bike lanes are sometimes done better, with zones near intersections which indicate to merge or that the bike lane and right lane cross each other. I find this much better than the lanes which encourage bikes to ride to the right of right-turners. Bike lanes which get this right, and are out of the door zone, I think avoid the majority of the issues you describe. I've also noticed more sharrows http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_lane_marking showing up a lot recently, especially in places where bike lanes need to end as the road becomes too narrow.

Comment: There was a change in the wording of the UK highway code that said bikes 'should' use the cycle lane - which meant it would be an offence to use the road if there was a cycle lane. I think it got turned down.

Comment: I think that bike lanes are good when done well. One issue that seems to come up is that lanes can foster a lack of awareness by the user. I've known of riders who've had accidents while using lanes and the root cause was lack of attention. They felt overly safe in the "bubble" of the lane. Not arguing against, just that a rider has to keep paying attention...

Comment: Article & video on the SLC bike lanes: http://www.ksl.com/index.php?nid=148&sid=4286822

Comment: I've not tried to actually measure this, but I definitely feel that on average, cars give me more space when I'm in a bike lane. This doesn't surprise me; as a driver I tend to center within my lane, so obviously I'd end up further from the road edge when there's a bike lane.

Answer (score 20):

In theory great except for:

Painted white line on side of road - great except for everybody turning right across them at each junction, cars parked in them, busses pulling in and out of them, grit+broken glass+leafs+litter swept into them, broken drain covers, or are so narrow you can't fit a bike in them. 
[image]

Separated bike lanes - either take you miles out of your way to give you a scenic route, or go alongside a busy road until they come to a major junction or freeway ramp and then just end - starting again at the other side of the lethally dangerous part.
[image]

Bike lanes that are either positioned by people who are complete morons, or are cynically putting in the minimum bike lane they can to claim some sort of government target.
[image]

[image]

Images are from the famous [warrington cycle lanes](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/pete.meg/wcc/facility-of-the-month/book.htm) now available as a book:

Comment: +1. "We need bike lanes as in major European/American cities" they say and throw a fortune on this task. However they usually don't have expertice to accompany that fortune and let money be used right.

Comment: +1 I love the link!  I think that you should put this picture http://homepage.ntlworld.com/pete.meg/wcc/facility-of-the-month/October2008.htm in your post.

Comment: @sixtyfootersdude  - and nice to know even the Dutch can be daft  http://homepage.ntlworld.com/pete.meg/wcc/facility-of-the-month/February2009.htm

Comment: -1 - Your comment about badly-placed bike lanes is a good one, but it isn't an argument for or against bike lanes, it's commentary on substandard execution of the concept. Perhaps show this as an example and summarize the contents of your link?

Comment: The link is a famous collection of the worst bike lanes with photos. A common one here is for the cycle lanes to run parallel to the freeway - at each on/off ramp there is a little notice telling to cross when safe, where the cycle path crosses the ramp!

Comment: I just love that last image. So descriptive of the situation XD

Answer (score 10):

In London there are some new 'Cycle Superhighways' painted in blue with lots of associated signage (and publicity), they're envisaged as arterial routes from the edges of the city into the centre. Obviously they're only useful if your journey is close to where they are but they have had some quite obvious effects even in the few months of their official existence.

Pro:

- Everyone knows about them. On that route cyclists aren't just tolerated, they're expected and this makes everyone safer.
- Every traffic light has an Advanced Stop Line (ASL). This means that at all traffic lights the cyclists are very visible to the other waiting traffic. One frequent criticism is that cycle lanes often seem to melt away at pinch points, which is not the case here.
- it makes red light jumpers even more obvious. When a bundle of cyclists are waiting and someone jumps, it underlines to car drivers that we're not all at it.

Con:

- there are almost too many cyclists. The lanes are often clogged and overflowing into the rest of the road. While the road is the cyclists to use as well, there is still a feeling of "that's your blue bit, the black bit is for cars".
- it makes red light jumpers even more obvious. When a bundle of cyclists are waiting and someone jumps, it makes car drivers even more aggreived, "all these facilities and you still jump reds?"
- it underlines that bikes are different. I don't want different, I want respect and my fair share.

Comment: They also went a bit over the top in painted on road markings. In that special slippery plastic paint that is so entertaining in the rain.

Comment: Absolutely. There are a few corners on my normal route where that blue paint is positively dangerous when there's been the slightest rainfall.

Comment: I wouldn't put that they make red light jumpers more obvious as a con.  The more obvious those buggers are, the better as far as I'm concerned!  I try to be a good cyclist and when I'm a pedestrian nothing pisses me off more than being half way across a green pedestrian crossing just to nearly get knocked over by some tosspot who doesn't think the red traffic light applies to him (and it almost always is a him).

Comment: @GordonM you'll notice I put RLJs as both a pro and a con for that very reason. It's a pro because it highlights them - but the very fact that people do it on facilities that, for all their flaws, are high profile is definitely a con too. While it is wrong, it might make the whole cycling corpus look 'ungrateful' of the expense.

Comment: ASL are being phased out in the Netherlands as they proof less than fully safe and there are much better options, like separate green cycle for cyclists.

Answer (score 6):

I have not read all answers and comments so I might have missed a link already here, but I think [this](http://www.aviewfromthecyclepath.com/) is the best site for for arguments about all to do with cycling and road safety. On the right hand side you will find many internal links to posts in themes, like ['what works'](http://www.aviewfromthecyclepath.com/search/label/what%20works) or ['cycle paths'](http://www.aviewfromthecyclepath.com/search/label/cycle%20paths)

I am not able to give you useful quotes from each of the links as they contain so much information and the themes might not really meet the arguments or more likely be just about one detail instead of about all. And he has links to other sites, often with good arguments in their own right.

So far for David Hembrow's site, from here on it is my opinion.

As a Dutch cyclist, who grew up in the time our bike lanes and paths were at their lowest ebb, I do appreciate the lanes when done well. The famous painted line (also known as a painted bike gutter,) which every car driver ignores, is not much use. But when bikes are out in numbers and fill those lanes, the car drivers do pay more attention and parked cars will be rarer.
It took the Netherlands 30 years of experimenting and re-designing, and at this time there is a 'new' problem, too many cyclists for the existing infrastructure.

Separate lanes next to the road will work only when the cyclists have the same comfort and rights as the cars, can cycle on without dismounting and road design is done in such way the entrances and exits to the lanes work. Combined cycling and walking use is only possible when cyclist and pedestrians do not want to use the lane at the same time.

Bike routes away from roads might work in some cases, it will not work in all.
When the route between two main locations passes a pinch point where no work will make for bike safety, but there is an alternative route which is a bit longer but away from the cars, it might be worth investing in it.

In the Netherlands we have no cycle lanes on roads that allow cars to go 80 km/h (about 50 mph) or faster, there will often be cycle paths near the road but they might also use a different, often shorter, route.
Roads that are 50 km/h (about 30 mph) have bike lanes on road although off road lanes or near bike paths are around as well.
Most roads that are 30 km/h (about 20 mph) do not usually have separate bike infrastructure but many of those roads are no through roads for cars but allow bikes to use them to connect to other parts of town.

That makes that almost no bikes and cars need to use the same road surface without the need for bike lanes and paths everywhere. We still do have more bike paths in a small country than most big countries, not only relative to size but also in actual km/miles. While at the same time we have fewer car/bike accidents and deaths from them.

The one area where deaths of cyclists goes up is in the over 65 (or even over 75) age group, as people keep cycling and now often get e-bikes and go the allowed 25km/h while not used to those speeds anymore, if they ever have been that is. Most of those accidents are one sided, the cyclist falling, hitting something near the path or road or just dropping over when having a heart attack.

Answer (score 5):

Bike lanes often have dirty, inferior roadway and angry SUV drivers eager to force you into the bicycle ghetto.
An extra wide right lane is a much better solution:

- Roadway is kept in better repair
- Roadway is swept clean by normal traffic flow
- Cyclists are not bullied by inattentive or bully drivers
- Wide right lanes are cheaper and easier than special bike lanes

Comment: Any chance you can expand on this? Even with the rest of your post, "Bike lanes suck" isn't going to convince anyone, and you also have some pretty stiff competition on this page.

Comment: I think what neilfein is trying to ask is: Why are roadways kept in better repair? Why are cyclists not bullied? Why are wide lanes cheaper? Etc...

Comment: @Joe, @Michael - That's part of it, certainly, but I was really hoping for answers that were more comprehensive, like the ones above. This answer reads like an napkin outline for a good answer to be written later.

Comment: The point is that the bike lanes where you cycle are not good or not kept up as the rest of the road, not that cycle lanes as such as not good. Where I live cycle lanes are better kept than normal lanes, so it can be done.

Answer (score 3):

I find that bike lanes are helpful in getting beginners comfortable riding "in traffic", except that then they also learn that they "can't" ride on roads without them.

Comment: +1 I tried to say the same thing, but this wording is perfect!

Comment: If that is true where you live, it is because the bike lanes and roads are not designed right. When the infrastructure is right, the step up is natural.

Answer (score 3):

The problem in the UK is that for every well designed useful bike lane there are at least 10 useless bike lanes created that just lead to drivers forcing you of the road.

In the UK bike lanes seems to be a “trick list” item that are mostly not wide enough to be of value and stop as soon as you get to a junction.  There seems to be no willingness to take road space away from motor cars on the sections of roads/junctions that would benefit most from bike lanes as reducing the capacity of a road is unthinkable.

Answer (score 2):

The table/graph "Preferred separation of bicycles and motor vehicles" (Ausroads, 2009) as visible here (Australian Bicycling Council, Cycling on Higher Speed Roads
When to Provide for Bicycles 
on Higher Speed Roads) on page 2: http://www.austroads.com.au/abc/images/pdf/ns1525_fs_one.pdf indicates that the Australian standard for introducing cycle lanes (being separately marked spaces on a public road) in an urban environment is centered at 5000 vehicle movements a day with the 85th percentile of speed being 55km/h.  If we consider the abominable "shoulder lane" of Australian practice to be a genuine bicycle lane then this would be extended into higher speeds and fewer traffic movements.

The road treatments suggested by Ausroads rarely come to fruition in NSW, with separated facilities almost always being inappropriate routed shared use paths with broken sight lines, corners well below speed, or merely being remarked standard footpaths neighbouring roads.  Where such paths are routed appropriately for commuting, such as the Illawarra's SUP Coastline Cycleway there are still numerous engineering flaws such as redundant curves, edge encroachment, failure to route mark.

Australian path building practice, road marking practice, or route marking of mixed traffic routes rarely follows this practice in urban environments in NSW.

Imagine, if you will, civil engineers who when responsible for constructing infrastructure are hindered at every turn, and whose responsibility to produce a road or way has been converted into the production of a leisure amenity for children.

Answer (score 0):

My take is the following: There are no con's for bike lanes! :-)

Think of it: Are there discussions of pro's and con's of sidewalks (aka pedestrian lanes)? No! Why? Because they are useful! It's a matter of protecting the fragile against the one ton metal boxes that are propelled at 50km/h!

However, there are many con's for how local politics have decided to implements bike lanes because they fail the purpose of it: there are inconsistencies, they are not enough separated from the road, they are placed dangerously, etc. Each time we witness such mistakes which should contact our local council and tell them about it. OK, I agree, it's not always useful, where I live they don't listen at all. But that's why there is elections, and I vote where my mouth is!

[In Toulouse](http://goo.gl/maps/ezsj), bike lanes are nice but improperly done in most cases. They can even lead you to a one way street with no bike lane and you will be against the traffic ([rue A. Dauménil](http://goo.gl/maps/lY1y))! Or they share part of the sidewalks leaving no room for pedestrians ([allée M. Sarraut](http://goo.gl/maps/cJKJ)). Or they share the road (just a bit of paint) and suddenly the road gets narrow and you get squeeze between a car and a high sidewalk ([avenue C. Pujol](http://goo.gl/maps/XSe6)), which means you are in danger! So yes, bike lanes in Toulouse have lots of con's, I just hope they will do a better job at it.

Comment: You're wrong - simply because bike lanes encourage in the motorist (as group and in at least in some countries) the belief that cycles do not belong on the road at all.

Comment: @Murph then this is bad communications by the politics who installed the bike lanes. :-) There are numerous countries or places where this is not the case: Netherlands, Germany, some parts of France (esp. the Eastern regions).

Comment: "You're wrong" is a bit of an over-statement :) I hope you can do better at communicating too ;)

Comment: No, actually it isn't an overstatment - you state, "there are no cons" and I state one that exists in a great many places regardless of quality of implementation (I agree that its by no means universal, I know from experience that in Denmark and Holland the relationship between motorist and cyclist is much better so its not the case). Cycle lanes are good in theory and when done properly and when integrated into the traffic system as a whole and when the attitude of the motorist is sympathetic to the cyclist. When we get to "separate but equal" it works rather less well.

Comment: You didn't get what I was saying. A cycle lane is not wrong in it's self (it's neutral), much like wine is not wrong (unless it tastes like vinegar), it's the use of it that could be wrong. So in the case of bike lanes, if it feels wrong in some places it's because it was poorly implemented and badly managed. So we shall not speak of bicycle lane as bad or good, this can't be, it's just a necessity. Please re-read my answer.

Comment: @Murph - Rather than refuting this one in the comments, it sounds like you could probably write your own answer to this question.

Comment: @Huygens - far too philosophical. Can a cycle lane (a well implemented, safe, sensible, useable cycle lane) be bad? Yes if it engenders in the motorist an opinion that cyclist should never be on the road and, sadly, in the UK it does in some. So emphatically yes cycle lanes can have cons. You're being far too clever and this is actually quite simple.

Comment: @neilfein - well I could, I suppose, but I'm afraid I'd mostly be repeating other people... but that doesn't make the opening statement right which is a shame because the rest is valuable (which is why I haven't downvoted it).

Comment: @Murph - No issue with repeating parts of what others have said, as long as you can improve it or have a different take on the material.

Comment: @Murph - ok then a more pragmatic view would be that we need to improve the understanding in politician minds that cycle lanes are much needed but it is not just about putting a bit of paint on the road. It takes heavy thinking and communication to all road users (pedestrians to drivers).

Comment: *Sigh* its nothing to do with politicians. There is a significant chunk of MOTORISTS that think that cycles do not belong on the road  - in these motorists cycle lanes encourage and reinforce this belief. Yes, this is an education problem, no its not right but sadly it is a fact (not helped by poor behaviour of some cyclists in disregarding traffic regulations).

Comment: Small story: "A worker has to do a task within 1 week. After a week of hard work the task is still unfinished and the project gets delayed. The customer is unhappy so the worker's getting blamed for that." That's the obvious 1st reaction. But mine was: the manager is to blame! Either he wrongly evaluated the worker's aptitude or his planning's just plain wrong. Now back to the cycle lane, your view's the obvious a cycle lane (sidewalk?) can have pro's and con's. My view is, the implementation of a cycle lane or a sidewalk can be rightly or incorrectly done, hence the politician is to blame.

Comment: Demo: In Toulouse (Fr), there's a small street named "Ste Catherine", it's really narrow, the sidewalk's barely wide enough for a normal person and car cannot by pass a cyclist there. Toulouse has a high problem of driver desobedience. So the mayor decided to put small pillars (1m high) on the sidewalks to prevent cars to park there. However, when applied in Ste Catherine street, there was no place left for pedestrians to walk. So they walk on the road, and women with baby carriage too. Now cars gets angry about them. The problem are not sidewalk though, but the politicians that did that!

Comment: You are willfully missing two points - one: that I don't necessarily disagree with much of what you've said and two: that the problem is with other road users not with politicians and will exist even if the implementation of the facility is *perfect* (it may even be a greater problem in this case).

Comment: A con for bike lane is that it might be free to flow when the motorist side is completely jammed and not moving, and a con, that usually some newbie riding at 10 km/h might jam it easily, more so in rush hour, tempting people to over pass in risky manners.

Comment: @gaurwraith and Murph we human are unperfect, we do mistake, we also sometimes misbehave and this is fine. But We often don't want to recognise that and are blaming the others ("other road user" not me ;-) or "some newbie" but I wasn't ever one of course ;-) ) The thing is we have to share the available road infrastructures between all of us and that includes the young ones (who are experimenting/learning) the older ones (who might be more cautious) and any other person with every walk-of-life. We just have to share and the politics, road engineer should just try to make this task easier.

Comment: Replace newbie with someone going  slow on the middle of the lane. As for me, since I don't like this, I ride trying to leave place for overpass no matter if I go fast or chilling, and always take looks after me and allow people to pass if I see them trying to do so. But the point is that bike lanes are becoming too narrow as number of cyclists increases. The problem where I live is that there is no possibility to widen many of them lest you remove a "car" lane

Comment: Translated to con, bike lanes as understood these days, are too narrow and easily clogged to absorb significant bicycle traffic. A car sized lane put to bicycle use would be wonderful

Comment: *Are there discussions of pro's and con's of sidewalks (aka pedestrian lanes)?* Well, yes, there is actually. That's where the concepts of living street and shared space come from and you can find designs [doing away entirely with the separation between the sidewalk and the rest of the road](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woonerf). You can also find many places in the world with no sidewalks, not as a fancy design but simply because pedestrians are not a priority and people are expected to move by car (the drawback here is costs and lost space for automobiles).

Answer (score 0):

In theory the bike lane is a good however in practice for major cities (middle of Manhattan, New York, USA) there is way too much traffic and not wide enough space.

The bike lanes in New York now place parked cars in between cyclist and motorists but it’s confusing.  Try crossing the street it’s confusing you have to essentially cross twice because you have to avoid getting hit by a cyclist who do not stop at red lights and then cross the motorist portion of the road.

Then those who are parked risk getting hit by a car because you can not open the passenger side door unless cars are at a standstill. So loading and unloading children from the cars is unsafe now that the parked cars are ill placed.

Also these lanes as on the left side of the road and statistically left turns are 7 times more dangerous then right turns so I have a green light I’m turning left and cyclist also have green light it’s an accident waiting to happen.

There is an increase in car damages like side view mirrors being knocked off because the cars driving on the now narrow road are too close to the now parked cars that separate the bike lane.

Comment: This comes across as a bit of a rant, rather than making a point and providing supporting information.   However there are some good points in here.